# Unable to locate element by name

Tags: selenium, webdriver, element

Can someone please explain to me why Selenium webdriver can't be find by `name=userid`?

```
<input class="required" type="text" size="15" maxlength="64" **name="userid"** 
value="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">
```

My code:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("userid")).sendKeys(prop.getProperty("userName"));
```

Error:

```
Unable to locate element: {"method":"name","selector":"userid"}
```

Comment: Yes, it is in frame and it is resolved after switching to main :) Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in my application there are frames involved and I didn't include switching to main as elements are in main frame.

To resolve this, I have simply add "driver.switchTo().frame("main");" before searching the element.

My final code are as below

```
driver.switchTo().frame("main");

driver.findElement(By.name("userid")).sendKeys(userName);
```

Hope my answer helps for those who are same on new (Webdriver boat) :)

Answer (score 0):

try below line of code and let me know:

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[contains(@name,'userid')]")).sendKeys(prop.getProperty("userName"));
```

Comment: Hint: if you put 4 whitespaces at the start of code line it will be formatted as code.

Comment: Thanks for replies :) 

Input was in the frame and i didn't select the frame. I have now included select main frame and it is working now.